# How to deal with GenericAliases with python 3.8 with compability with more recent versions?

Tags: python, compatibility, type-hinting, introspection

I need to do some introspection on dataclasses.
currently, the project is running on python 3.8, but soon, it will be upgraded. However, right now, I would like to know how I can check if a type is a GenericAlias, and get its t_orig, and t_args. How can I do is so that :

- On python 3.8 :

  - It works with typing.List[int]
- On python 3.9+ :

  - It works with typing.List[int]
  - It works with list[int]
- The same code works all 3.8+ versions

Comment: Does [`get_args`/`get_origin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_origin) not work for you? What exactly do you want to check? Just if something is `list[int]`/`List[int]` or something more general about generic alias types?

Comment: Yup, that's the solution I've found after I asked the question, and it's all I needed !